# If $\mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$ and $ g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ minimizes $ \mathbb{E}[(X -g(Y))^2]$, then $g(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $\mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty$. Show that if $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function that minimizes $ \mathbb{E}[(X -g(Y))^2]$, then $g(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$.

My approach -:
$\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$ also $\mathbb{E}[(X-g(Y))^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[(X-f(Y))^2]$ for function $f$ and somehow use the fact that

if $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)X] < \infty$ then $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)X \mid  Y] = f(Y)\mathbb{E}[X \mid  Y]$

I am not sure how to tie all this together and formulate a cohesive argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe
$$
\begin{align}
[X - g(Y)]^2 &= [X-\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] + \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)]^2 \\
&= \left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\right\}^2 + 2\left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\right\}\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\} \\
&\qquad + \left\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\right\}^2\text{}
\end{align}$$
Now, use linearity of expectation. We focus on the second term for now.
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{2\left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\right\}\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\}\right\}\tag{*}$$
By double expectation, write the above as
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left\{2\left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\right\}\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\}\mid Y\right\}\right\}$$
The term
$$\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\}$$
depends on $Y$ only and can be pulled out of the innermost expectation with the $2$, yielding
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{2\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\}\mathbb{E}\left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\mid Y\right\}\right\}$$
Furthermore,
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\mid Y\right\} = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] \mid Y] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] = 0$$
thus it follows that (*) gives $0$. Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[X - g(Y)]^2 = \mathbb{E}\left\{X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\right\}^2+ \mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\right\}^2\tag{**}$$
The first term of the right-hand side of (**) does not depend on $g(Y)$, so we ignore it. However, the second term does, and furthermore, it is a non-negative quantity, because it is an expectation of a squared quantity. Thus we know that
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\right\}^2$$
is minimized when
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\right\}^2 = 0$$
which is when
$$\left\{\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] - g(Y)\right\}^2 = 0$$
or $$g(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\text{.}$$

Comment: How do we know that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y] - g(Y)]^2$ is minimized when $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y] - g(Y)]^2 = 0$

Comment: @foobar Because the term in the expectation is non-negative, hence the expectation must be non-negative as well. If you have a non-negative quantity, it must be $\geq 0$, hence must be minimized at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{\mathbb{E}[X-g(Y)]^2=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}[x-g(Y)]^2f(x|Y)dx
\qquad (1)
}
$$

Let's derive (1)  with respect to $g(Y)$

$$-2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}[x-g(Y)]f(x|Y)dx$$

Set it =0 and we obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x|Y)dx=g(Y)\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x|Y)dx}_{=1}$$

thus

$$g(Y)=\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$$